# SQLSTATE=08001 error trying to connect to db2 remote db node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, db2

I am running my application as I have been for the past YEAR. today, db2 decided to give me this error:

```
 =https
2021-11-08T16:07:47.262433+00:00 app[web.1]: [Error: [IBM][CLI Driver] SQL30081N  A communication error has been detected. Communication protocol being used: "TCP/IP".  Communication API being used: "SOCKETS".  Location where the error was detected: "".  Communication function detecting the error: "selectForConnectTimeout".  Protocol specific error code(s): "115", "*", "*".  SQLSTATE=08001
2021-11-08T16:07:47.262443+00:00 app[web.1]: ] {
2021-11-08T16:07:47.262445+00:00 app[web.1]: error: '[node-ibm_db] SQL_ERROR',
2021-11-08T16:07:47.262445+00:00 app[web.1]: sqlcode: -30081,
2021-11-08T16:07:47.262446+00:00 app[web.1]: state: '08001'
2021-11-08T16:07:47.262446+00:00 app[web.1]: }
```

I am running my login function, which the query looks like this:

```
    var userLogin = "select * from login where USERNAME = ?";
  ibmdb.open(ibmdbconnMaster, function (err, conn) {
    if (err) return console.log(err);
    conn.query(userLogin, [inputUsername], function (err, rows) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
```

any chance anyone can help?

Comment: Study the technote https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/cli-application-fails-sql30081n-rc-115-selectforreceivetimeout-function

Comment: Your application doesn't change, but your environment does...

Comment: The 115 protocol specific code can also happen if the Db2-server is unreachable, or down, or the route to it has changed in some way as to be significantly slower than previously.  Most likely, something outside your application has changed, and you do not know about it as yet.   This is not a matter for stackoverflow, but is instead a matter for troubleshooting at your site. Speak with your DBA people.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Heroku application stopped serving db2 connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69888175/heroku-application-stopped-serving-db2-connection)