# Heroku application stopped serving db2 connection

Tags: node.js, ssl, heroku, db2

I have my app hosted on heroku for nearly 1 year, and in the past 24 hours, it stopped working. I get this in my logs:

```
 2021-11-08T18:15:06.475815+00:00 app[web.1]: [Error: [IBM][CLI Driver] SQL30081N  A communication error has been detected. Communication protocol being used: "TCP/IP".  Communication API being used: "SOCKETS".  Location where the error was detected: "".  Communication function detecting the error: "selectForConnectTimeout".  Protocol specific error code(s): "115", "*", "*".  SQLSTATE=08001
2021-11-08T18:15:06.475827+00:00 app[web.1]: ] {
2021-11-08T18:15:06.475828+00:00 app[web.1]: error: '[node-ibm_db] SQL_ERROR',
2021-11-08T18:15:06.475829+00:00 app[web.1]: sqlcode: -30081,
2021-11-08T18:15:06.475829+00:00 app[web.1]: state: '08001'
2021-11-08T18:15:06.475830+00:00 app[web.1]: }
2021-11-08T18:15:33.386490+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=POST path="/login" host=www.mysite.ca request_id=3d627300-28d2-48af-a86e-60bdb950298a fwd="99.249.30.56" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=30000ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
```

It seems to not like whatever is going on with `db2`. I can access my database no problem through my local machine, and see everything with in my db tables. I also have this directly from my heroku dashboard.

[image]

[image]

i am not able to figure out what the issue is. does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: You have the same symptom in two questions. The other question is : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69886593/sqlstate-08001-error-trying-to-connect-to-db2-remote-db-node-js

Comment: @mao sorry didn't respond to you on the other question. You are correct, I do have the same symptom. But now I do realize it is a heroku based issue, so hoping someone can help me out on the heroku side.

Comment: Has your database server changed somehow? New version, new configuration, etc.?

Comment: Please don't re-post questions. You should have edited your old question to add the Heroku information if you believe it is relevant.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQLSTATE=08001 error trying to connect to db2 remote db node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69886593/sqlstate-08001-error-trying-to-connect-to-db2-remote-db-node-js)

Comment: @gianlps is the Db2-connection encrypted (tls/ssl)?  Can another jdbc application connect to the same database with the __same__ connection-string?  Might not be a heroku problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to everyone for their answers. I did some more digging around, and turns out what solved it was reinstalling the db2 driver locally, and pushing it to heroku. Something must have changed that required an update to the db2 driver to connect with the heroku sevrer.